# NSMutableArray remove objectAtIndex NSRangeException IOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, nsrangeexception

I get `NSRangeException` error when I try to `removeObjectAt:0` . I don't know how that is even possible.

```
-(void)removePoints:(ccTime *)tm
{

    NSLog(@"naughty %@",_naughtytoucharray);
    if ([_naughtytoucharray count]>0)
    {
        [_naughtytoucharray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

shows on log:

`[4195:c07] naughty (
    "{124, 98}",
    "{123, 98}",
    "{135, 97}",
    "{124, 98}",
    "{148, 94}",
    "{135, 97}",
    "{157, 93}",
    "{148, 94}",
    "{162, 92}",
    "{157, 93}",
    "{164, 92}",
    "{162, 92}"
)`

then I get the following error:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'`

When I set a breakpoint I see all objects are `0x0`

[image]

`NSMutableArray` is allocated and initialized in `init` and filled in `ccTouchesMoved`

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {


    if (isSelected) {

        UITouch *touch = [ touches anyObject];
        CGPoint new_location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        new_location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:new_location];


        CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
        oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
        oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

        // add my touches to the naughty touch array
        [_naughtytoucharray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(new_location)];
        [_naughtytoucharray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(oldTouchLocation)];

    }
}
```

Any idea why I cannot remove the first item of the array?

Comment: See if accessing your mutable array with its property `self.naughtytoucharray` makes a diffrent.

Comment: I'm guessing you screwed up something pretty badly in storage management, and the array is getting corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not where your error is coming from.  The method it's complaining about is `objectAtIndex:`, not `removeObjectAtIndex:` and the index causing the error is eleven, not zero.

Look for a place in your code where you are assuming that there are at least 12 objects in the array while reading from it.  There are only eleven and their indexes are 0-to-10.

Comment: ok I get what you mean, I read array every frame in `-(void)draw`